# create optimum data structure python

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures

I am cross referencing two data sources which share 6 common fields. The idea is the the marketing costs in file 1 are split out over the sales transactions in file 2. I've written a way to build a data structure from the first file so that the second one can access it quickly, but it seems un-pythonic to me. I'm interested to get some input and opinions on whether anyone thinks it could be written in a better way.

```
cost_matrix = {}
for line in marketing_costs:
    line_date_object = time.strptime(line['date'], "%d/%m/%Y")
    period = '%04d_%02d' % (line_date_object.tm_year, line_date_object.tm_mon)
    territory = line['territory'].lower()
    salesperson=line['salesperson'].lower()
    customer_type = line['customer_type'].lower()
    affiliate=line['affiliate'].lower()
    product_group = line['product_group'].lower()
    line_mktg_cost=line['mktg_cost']
    try:
        cost_matrix[period]
    except KeyError:
        cost_matrix[period]={}
    try:
        cost_matrix[period][territory]
    except KeyError:
        cost_matrix[period][territory]={}
    try:
        cost_matrix[period][territory][salesperson]
    except KeyError:
        cost_matrix[period][territory][salesperson]={}
    try:
        cost_matrix[period][territory][salesperson][customer_type]
    except KeyError:
        cost_matrix[period][territory][salesperson][customer_type]={}
    try:
        cost_matrix[period][territory][salesperson][customer_type][affiliate]
    except KeyError:
        cost_matrix[period][territory][salesperson][customer_type][affiliate]={}
    try:
        cost_matrix[period][territory][salesperson][customer_type][affiliate][product_group]
    except KeyError:
        cost_matrix[period][territory][salesperson][customer_type][affiliate][product_group]={}
        cost_matrix[period][territory][salesperson][customer_type][affiliate][product_group]['mktg_cost']=0
    cost_matrix[period][territory][salesperson][customer_type][affiliate][product_group]['mktg_cost']+=Decimal(line_mktg_cost)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every one of those 4-line `try`/`except` blocks can be replaced by a 1-liner using [`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

> `setdefault(key[, default])`
>
> - If *key* is in the dictionary, return its value. If not, insert *key* with a value of *default* and return *default*. *default* defaults to `None`.

So this:

```
cost_matrix[period].setdefault(territory, {})
```

… is equivalent to:

```
try:
    cost_matrix[period][territory]
except KeyError:
    cost_matrix[period][territory]={}
```

Except that you can use it in a larger expression, which means in theory you can turn the whole thing into one giant expression if you want to, although I'm not sure I'd do that.

---

You can simplify things even further by using a recursive [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). A `defaultdict` is basically just a `dict` that handles missing keys by set-defaulting automatically, and a recursive one does so with another `defaultdict` instead of a plain `dict`. (You do still need one `setdefault` or just plain key assignment at the end to handle the default of `0` instead of yet another dict…)

Like this:

```
_make_defaultdict = lambda: defaultdict(_make_defaultdict)
recursive_defaultdict = defaultdict(_make_defaultdict)

cost_matrix = recursive_defaultdict()
cost_matrix[period][territory][salesperson][customer_type][
    affiliate][product_group]['mktg_cost'] = 0
cost_matrix[period][territory][salesperson][customer_type][
    affiliate][product_group]['mktg_cost'] += Decimal(line_mktg_cost)
```

However, be aware that this means you'll never get a `KeyError` anywhere else in your code either. If that's not acceptable, then stick with `setdefault`. (Although if you're basically building the dict up, then using it, you can "freeze" it into a normal `dict` just by recursively copying it…)

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Thanks for catching and fixing the typo.

Comment: Thank you this is great! i will use the setdefault because other parts of the script depend on KeyError exceptions.

Comment: @TommyGaboreau: There's also a recipe on ActiveState somewhere for a recursive defaultdict that you can freeze and unfreeze on the fly, if you want to search for that. (I used it once just because it's such a neat idea, but I've never used it again in real code because I've never had a good use for it… but maybe you do.)

Comment: it's good to know that such a thing exists but for now your setdefault solution is perfect. Thank You.